# How to iterate through a list and get all items stored in a variable in a specific format

Tags: python, loops, for-loop, iteration

My program is supposed to take input for a list 'reg':

```
reg = []
while True:
    c = input('Enter applicable regs: ')
    if c == '':
        break
    reg.append(c.upper())
```

List `reg` would be like `['USPR', 'OSFI', 'EMIR', ...]`

Now I'd want to iterate through each of the items, and store them in a variable so that the variable x looks like below:

```
x = '[USPR,OSFI,EMIR]'
```

given there are 3 inputs from the user.

How to accomplish this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `join()` to concatenate list elements with a delimiter. Then concatenate the brackets around it.

```
x = '[' + ','.join(reg) + ']'
```

Comment: More join fun: `','.join(reg).join('[]')`

Comment: That's silly. :)

Comment: @dkdtd If this answer solves your question, please mark it as the accepted answer so others can find their solution faster. Thank you.